# ImageIcon in JTableCell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, imageicon, tablecellrenderer

I am having an issue adding an ImageIcon to my JLabel in my JTable. So far I am entirely able to manipulate the cell based on the value of the data in the cell however whenever I try to add in an image I am only seeing the text.

**Table Renderer**

```
class DeviceTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private Object[][] data = Globals.getArray();
    private String[] columnNames = {"Name","Status","Description"};


    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0,c).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);
    }

}
```

**This is the Renderer I am using in my JTable.**

```
 @Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
    JLabel comp = (JLabel)super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
    Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, col);

    if (value.equals("online")) {
        comp.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Res/online.png"));
        comp.setBackground(Color.green);
    }else {
        comp.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    return comp;
}
```

The color and text set just fine but the icon will not display. Any ideas would be appreciated!

**EDIT- Suggestions by VGR and Camickr**

Your advice was spot on and resolved the issue! Take a look at the redone portion. I am very grateful. Thanks guys!

```
 //preloaded just added here to show. 
 ImageIcon icon = new  ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Res/onlineIcon.png"));


 @Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
    JLabel comp = (JLabel)super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
    Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, col);

    if (value.equals("online")) {
        comp.setIcon(icon);
        comp.setBackground(new Color(173,255,92));
    }else {
        comp.setIcon(null);
        comp.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
    return comp;
}
}
```

Comment: The [ImageIcon constructor documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.lang.String-) makes it clear that the string argument is a filename.  Unless your system has a `Res` directory in the root of the file system, you probably meant to do `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Res/online.jpg"))` or `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/online.jpg"))`.  Note that your `else` clause should be setting the icon to null, since a single renderer may be used for multiple table cells.

Comment: 1) Is the code being executed? Add a println(...) statement to verify. 2) Is the image being read? Also, it is not a good idea to continually read the image in the prepareRenderer() method. Rendering code should be fast. The image should be preloaded.

Comment: Oh you guys are so awesome. @VGR you were correct in how I was calling the resource! camickr I took your advice and preloaded the image and it is much much faster now. You guys rock. VGR please add your answer as a real answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ImageIcon constructor documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.lang.String-) makes it clear that the string argument is a filename.  Unless your system has a `Res` directory in the root of the file system, you probably meant to do `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Res/online.jpg"))` or `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/online.jpg"))`.

Note that your `else` clause should be setting the icon to null, since a single renderer may be used for multiple table cells.